# How to make parametric equations with curly brace

Tags: braces, cases

I'm using

```
$\begin{cases} x=3 + 2\sin t \\ y= 4+\sin t \end{cases}$
```

to write parametric equations but I want to add the domain in the middle of the two equations like in this picture.

How can I add it?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You  can write the condition just after the cases environment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \[\begin{cases}
        x=3+2\sin t\\
        y=4+\sin t
    \end{cases}
    t\in (-\infty,\infty)\]
\end{document}
```