# How to make a parametric equation of surface with curly brace

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment

I want to write the intervals for `t` and `u` on the left side like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/356100/191462) but that is only one equation and when I try

```
\[\begin{cases}
x = sin(u)cos(t) \\
y = sin(u)sin(t) \\
z = cos(u) 
\end{cases}
{ 1 < t < 2\pi \\ 0 < u < \pi }
\]
```

What I got is the intervals get concatenated like this 1 < t < 2\pi0 < u < \pi
[image]

I want to get both vertical centers aligned, and get intervals for t and u in two different lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX! You need to wrap the inequations in an `aligned` environment or something similar:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{cases}
x = sin(u)cos(t) \\
y = sin(u)sin(t) \\
z = cos(u) 
\end{cases}
\begin{aligned} 
1 < t &< 2\pi \\ 
0 < u &< \pi 
\end{aligned}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]